# Android & Java inner class concept

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, nested-class

i followed the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html and i try to create new AlertDialog like this

```
AlertDialog myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
```

as per the document AlerDialog is the outerclass and Builder is the inner class within AlertDialog. Now i linked the same concept with java in accessing the inner class like this `Outer myOuter2 = new Outer.Inner();` this piece of gives error when i try to access, here is the complete java code

```
package com.test;

    public class Outer {
        public void OuterMethod() {
            System.out.println("OuterMethod");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Outer myOuter = new Outer();

            myOuter.OuterMethod();
            Outer myOuter2 = new Outer.Inner();//this piece of code gives error

        }

        class Inner {

            Inner() {
                System.out.println("constructor Inner");
            }

            public void InnerMethod() {
                System.out.println("Inside InnerMethod");
            }
        }
    }
```

so my question over here is how to understand the same inner class concept in android and accessing the methods within that

Comment: _What does the error say_?

Comment: Make `class Inner` static + Duncan's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have created an inner non-static class (an inner *instance* class), whereas `AlertDialog.Builder` is a static class.

To get your code to work as is you need an [interesting way of invoking `new`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) that goes like this:

```
Outer.Inner myOuter2 = myOuter.new Inner();
```

This is because it acts much like any other non-static field within Outer - it requires an instance of Outer in order to be valid. In any event, this is often not a good idea as **public** inner non-static classes are rare.

More likely you want `Inner` to be a static class, i.e. one declared as:

```
static class Inner {
```

Essentially this decouples `Inner` from its containing class, it just happens to live inside it and so can be instantiated via `new Outer.Inner()`. It could happily live as a public class in its own right in a new .java file instead.

Inner static classes are useful when the inner class is only used in relation the outer class, so it shows the relationship between them.

In Android's case you use an `AlertDialog.Builder` only when building an `AlertDialog`. If it was a general `Builder` used by other classes (e.g. a plain `Dialog`) is would have instead been declared as its own public class (i.e. a standalone class that is not nested inside another).

Answer (score 6):

There is no relationship between `Outer` and `Inner` except that they share a class file. Hence, you cannot type:

```
Outer myOuter2 = new Outer.Inner();
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
Outer.Inner myInner = new Outer.Inner();
```

The `Inner` class will need to be declared as `static` for this to work.

---

Note that a normal builder will return a type that is equal to the enclosing type. Here's a small example using similar class names to your code:

```
public class Outer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer outer = new Outer.Builder().withParam("foo").build();
  }

  private final String someParam;

  private Outer(String someParam) {
    this.someParam = someParam;
  }

  public static class Builder {

    private String someParam;

    public Builder() {
    }

    public Builder withParam(String value) {
      this.someParam = value;
      return this;
    }

    public Outer build() {
      return new Outer(someParam);
    }
  }
}
```

You may also wish to read Item #2 of Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java, 2nd Edition* for a good description of builder design and rationale. Available online: [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2).

Comment: That only takes care of one problem.

Comment: Inner needs to be a static inner class.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner class is non static type.
We should first create instance of your outer class:

```
Outer o=new Outer();
Outer.Inner oi=o.new Inner();
```

This is the basic way of create non static inner class object.

Suppose if your inner is of type static (i.e. `static class Inner{....}`), 
then for creating object:

```
Outer.Inner oi=new Outer.inner();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AlertDialog.Builder` class is a static inner class as you can see [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/9f03d4f921fab5757a791653891ce73c2d006e20/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java#L352-L954).

```
public static class Builder {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out here is the code

```
package com.test;

public class Outer {
    public void OuterMethod() {
        System.out.println("OuterMethod");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer myOuter = new Outer();

        myOuter.OuterMethod();
        Outer myOuter2 = new Outer.Inner().InnerMethod();
    }

    static class Inner {

        Inner() {
            System.out.println("constructor Inner");
        }

        public Outer InnerMethod() {
            Outer myOuter = new Outer();
            System.out.println("Inside InnerMethod");
            return myOuter;

        }
    }
}
```